# Target First Div Image CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors

I'm modifying a poorly designed website for a client. The original developer placed the same header code in every page which means editing all the individual files really isn't an option.

Here is a sample of the code.

```
<div class="col-md-3 text-left">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
</div>
```

So it's pretty hard to edit that logo image because it doesn't even have a class attached to it..

Is there a way for me to make a CSS rule that will only  apply to the first time the `col-md-3` class is called and then edit that img.
Something like this:

```
img.col-md-3:first{
    width:171px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: No, it sounds like you're after a `first-of-class` selector and that doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you want only one instance of `col-md-3` to be affected? Meaning, if there are several `col-md-3` on the page you only want the first one that is found to be affected.

Comment: @disinfor Yes, zer00ne has the solution below.

Comment: @ShivamPaw Nope. That won't work. Anytime `col-md-3` is found in a new containing element, the image in that container will also be affected.

Comment: @disinfor What do you mean? It seems to be working: www.medicalstudieseurope.co.uk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going with what you described:

```css
div.col-md-3:first-of-type img {
  width: 171px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  /* For Testing */
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 text-left">
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Intel-logo.svg/2000px-Intel-logo.svg.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Note to the reader: Although in @ShivamPaw 's situation this snippet resolves the problem, keep in mind of what @disinfor has stated in that if `div.col-md-3` were to be found in a new containing element, the image in that container will also be affected within the same page.

In @ShivamPaw 's description I'm assuming through context:

- A header on each page.
- logo.png

These factors lead me to the conclusion the solution I posted will work (and it did , fortunately)

Comment: As a heads up, this will select any `.col-md-3` that appear in new containing elements, not only the first one that appears on the page.

Comment: *It helps if you post the whole mess to get an accurate perspective, but going with what you described:* is part of my answer.

Comment: @zer00ne Absolutely! I understand what you're getting at, I just wanted to point that out for completeness. It's all good!

Comment: Indeed I agree, sir. I'll include that in the post, thanks.

Comment: @zer00ne May I suggest you move the _It helps if you..._ part to a comment, where it belongs, and keep _With what you described..._, and you'll get a +1 from me

Comment: Agreed, with the added note, the other half is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery if that possible using :first selector to add a class or direct css values:

```
$( ".col-md-3:first" ).find( "img" ).css( "width", "171px" ).css( "padding-bottom","10px").....;
```

or if this logo is only used in this place

```
 $( "img[src='img/logo.png']").css( "width", "171px" ).css( "padding-bottom","10px").....;
```